# Mysql inserts blank field from php script, but not in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I inserted data through the phpmyadmin into my table. It shows me the query it uses so I copied and pasted it into my php code.

My Php code is suppose to be submitting a form and I am trying to get $_POST('name') into the query.When I run the code it fills everything out but the ***version_name*** field where name goes.

Funny thing is im using the same MYSQL query that inserts it correctly on the phpmyadmin.

I have moved on to trying a random name not the POST to see if it submits but i keep getting a blank... any suggestions?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Prototype`.`Version` ('version_id', `version_name`, `version_status`, `created_date`, `created_by`) VALUES ('','A', 'A', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL);";
```

this is the Insert part, and I have also tried removing the version_id since it is autoincramented but no help.

[image]

the first row is what the result looks like when submitted from my php. the second row is when I insert it right from phpmyadmin.

[image]

Any help getting version_name to be submitted from my php would be wonderful!

edit----

Heres my php code

```
    <?php

// Retrieve form data
$name = $_POST['name'];

if (!$name) {
    echo "save_failed";
    return;
}


$db = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'Prototype',
);

$link = @mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['login'], $db['password']);
if (!$link) {
    echo "save_failed";
    return; 
}
mysql_select_db($db['database']);

// Clean variables before performing insert
$clean_name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);


// Perform insert
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Prototype`.`Version` (`version_name`, `version_status`, `created_date`, `created_by`) VALUES ( 'A', 'A', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL);";

if (@mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "success";
    @mysql_close($link);
    return;
} else {
    echo "save_failed";
    @mysql_close($link);
    return;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with the server. I deleted the database and started from scratch and it solved the issue. Almost went as far as uninstalling and reinstalling xampp.

Answer (score 0):

firs thing first `$_POST('name');` is nothing `$_POST['name'];` is right. Now answer to your question use following query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Prototype`.`Version` (`version_name`, `version_status`, `created_date`, `created_by`) VALUES ('A', 'A', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL)";
```

I have also checked it on my own table made from structure provided by you.
it's query is given below.

```
CREATE TABLE `proto` (  `version_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `version_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  `version_status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  `created_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Below code is for you to submit it via php.

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.";charset=utf8", USERNAME, PASSWORD, $options);
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `Prototype`.`Version` 
                                   (`version_name`, 
                                    `version_status`, 
                                    `created_date`, 
                                    `created_by`) 
                                   VALUES 
                                  ('A', 
                                   'A', 
                                   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                   NULL)");
$result = $query->execute();
return $result ? true : false;
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the PDO but once I tried your code I still got a blank field for version_name

Comment: If you could check out my php code above to see if that works for you!? This has been really frustrating ahah but thank you so much for your help

Comment: the issue is that even if I use a string like 'auga' or anything instead of just the POST[name] it still inserts a blank. Im starting to think its a problem with phpmyadmin not so much the code

Comment: Hello I have tried your php code with a little modification please check it here http://pastebin.com/4XjhX5bk and assign `$name=$_POST['version'];` instead of my assignment. If you still get blank field then I think there is something wrong in your way of posting data so please show me the code inside `<form></form>` tag.

Comment: and 1 more thing, have you tried creating your table with the create table query I posted above and then try to insert data?

Comment: And 1 last thing please run the following the following query and post the results I wanna see your table structure

`SHOW CREATE TABLE Version`

Comment: Iv uploaded up loaded just about all the relevant code. I tried your code but once again still a blank field.

Comment: I want to make sure you understand that if it wont even shows blank in a text string to the database then how is it going to submit a post im trying to find out why nothing will show. It works in the fact that it inserts just leaves the version_name blank. But seriously thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This many be by the by, and not an answer to your question but in Mysql 4 this would work:

An auto increment value can be

- left out completely, if you state named fields
- NULL
- 0
- '' (empty string)

From Mysql 5 the last one will not work.

It was an undocumented feature of Mysql 4 which was removed for Mysql 5.

Comment: Thank you! I was not completely sure which was the more correct way of doing the whole auto increment thing. Iv played around with it but still not much change on the blank field.